# updating a table with action button

Tags: action, server, shiny

I am trying to develop a very basic shiny app. The ui script is very simple

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Drawing a Dice"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("action", label = "Draw"),
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text1")
    )
  )
))
```

But i am not sure how to go about doing the server. R

I need the server.R to do the following: Every time the user clicks on draw,it draws a random number from 1:6 and fills the 1st cell of a 10 cell array. And for every click on done till 10 ,it repeats the job. The eventual outcome will be a length 10 vector with random numbers between 1 to 6. In need to give the user an option of exiting by clicking on finish. But i need to be able to retrieve the final resultant vector after closing the app. 
Hence the server.R needs to perform the following operation in a one step increments

```
draw<-function(){
  Dice<-c(1:6)
  Mydraws<-numeric(10)
  for(i in 1:10){
    x<-sample(Dice,1,replace=TRUE)
    Mydraws[i]=x
  }
  Mydraws
}
```

Hence ,i should be able to fetch the Mydraws vector even after user exits by clicking on finish(not included in ui.R)

I do not even know if its possible in shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

server.R

```
numbers <- list()

shinyServer(function(input, output) 
{
    output$array <- renderText({
        # the presence of input$action will cause this to be evaluated each time the button is clicked
        # the value gets incremented each time you click it, which is why we use it as the index of the list

        random_number <- sample(1:6,1)

        # add to the global variable
        numbers[input$action] <<- random_number

        return(random_number)
    })
})
```